# Java convert Spring Data Sort to Comparator

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, comparator

I built a Spring Boot application that uses the Spring Data Sort class to sort the entities in my database. 
However, for reasons of consistency, I'd also like to apply that sort mechanism to general lists or streams and therefore need to convert it to a `Comparator`.

I came up with a solution but I feel like there is a more elegant and/or type-safe way of doing it. Any advice?

```java
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import java.beans.IntrospectionException;
import java.beans.PropertyDescriptor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class ComparatorUtils {
    public static <T> Comparator<T> convert(Sort sort, Class<T> type) {
        final Iterator<Sort.Order> orderIterator = sort.iterator();
        final Sort.Order order = orderIterator.next();

        Comparator<T> comparator = convert(order, type);
        while (orderIterator.hasNext()) {
            comparator = comparator.thenComparing(convert(orderIterator.next(), type));
        }

        return comparator;
    }

    private static <T> Comparator<T> convert(Sort.Order order, Class<T> type) {
        Comparator<T> comparator = Comparator.comparing((T entity) -> {
            try {
                return (Comparable) new PropertyDescriptor(order.getProperty(), type).getReadMethod().invoke(entity);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | IntrospectionException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });

        if (order.isDescending())
            return comparator.reversed();
        return comparator;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the question belongs to the [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) portal of Stack exchange

Comment: @Evertrude you should post this as a gist on github. I am sure other people want to help  improve this code.

Answer (score 0):

- Use org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.getPropertyDescriptor where the descriptors are cached (instead of new PropertyDescriptor).
- This solution doesn't handle sorting by deeper fields (eg. Person.Address.Street)
- Null values aren't correctly handled. Use Comparator.nullsFirst or nullsLast.

Comment: I removed question from the end of my answer. Now it contains only advises as an answer for the main question.